# PJSIP - Connect on multicast ipaddress (send/receive rtp packets)

Tags: c++, qt, pjsip, pjsua2

I should to connect on multicast ipaddress (239.0.0.2:4000) and send/receive rtp packets in PCMA format (without sip protocol).
If it's possible, how can I implement this feature on my application?

Best Regards

Comment: Do you want to set priority of sound codec you send to PCMA?